# windows 10 does not discover DVD device

Tags: usb, windows-10, dvd

This is a BR-DVD (ASUS SBC-06D2X-U) device plugged in USB port.

Device is present in the BIOS and can be booted from.
It is also present when machine runs Ubuntu or previous version W 8.1

Under Windows10, the device does not appear either in the device manager or in the disk management tool.

It was working with W8.1 before the migration to W10.
When I did the migration to W10 the device was not connected.
This might be at the source of the problem?

Comment: Look in devicemanagement for devices that are unknown or have a red X or a yellow traingle in the ico. Those can be a incorrectly installed driver.

Comment: if you read the question, it is stated that the device management does not show the DVD

Comment: This problem keeps happening everytime there is a major update to Windows. 5th time I apply the solution here now :-(

Answer (score 13):

This drive that plugs into USB does not appear in Device manager but as a separate line item

-Initio Combo Device Class

```
    Initio Default Controller
```

also, there is no entry under the "USB Bus controllers" list.

To correct that:

De-activate and desinstall the "Initio Default Controller" and the drivers.

Unplug the DVD from the USB port - then power off the PC.

Plug the DVD - and restart the PC.

It should be OK now. It is present in Windows explorer with a drive letter.

In the device manager:
there is now an entry for Mass storage controller under the "USB bus controllers" list,
and a new line item for device "DVD/CD-ROM readers"

Comment: Does the drive always have to be plugged in at startup, or can it be hotplugged in after sucessfully installing the driver per your process?

Comment: This works, thanks! I Uninstalled the device and checked for deleting the drivers. Then I simply, unplugged it, and plugged it back in without rebooting the system - still got the drive in My Computer

Comment: I agree with ogrim's comment:  as long as I did a right click - Uninstall the "Initio Default Controller" and selected the "Delete Driver" option presented in the pop-up, all I needed to do was unplug and plug in the device again, and it immediately detects it as a DVD/CD-ROM reader.